# Add Scrolling to Iframe From Iframe Code

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Let's say I have an iframe hosted on `www.my-iframe.com`. And let's say that my iframe is embedded in a page on a **different domain** using:

```
<iframe src="http://www.my-iframe.com" scrolling="no" height="500" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Please note that the iframe tag has the attribute `scrolling="no"`.

I only have access to edit the iframe code, not the pages on which my iframe is embedded. This makes it so I cannot change the `scrolling` attribute of the iframe html tag or the `overflow: hidden;` css styling of the iframe.

Is there a way that I can force a scroll bar to appear when necessary from within the iframe code?

Any help/advice is appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just use `overflow: scroll` (or auto) on your top-level element?

Comment: @BenKolyaMansley Doesn't seem to work. I added `body { overflow: scroll !important; }` to my css for my iframe and it still doesn't work when embedded in a page. Not sure if that's because the `scrolling="no"` in the html tag is overriding it. But it doesn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is maybe using a JS library to simulate a a scrollbar, there are plenty of them on the internet.
Here are a few examples (neither unordered nor necessarily the best ones):      [iScrollJS](http://iscrolljs.com/)
[fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage)
[jQuery scrollbars](https://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/)